# Postman Path Variables without slashs

Tags: api, postman, integration

I have a basic GET request with a `CustomerName` path variable that I am trying to access in Postman like so:

```
https://my-domain.com/../{{version}}/{{tenant}}/{{company}}/AR/ARCustomers(":CustomerName")
```

For some reason the `:` doesn't get recognized as a PATH variable without a `/` or `\` in front of it like so `/:`. Additionally the path variable will be seen as `CustomerName")` unless I escape the `"`. If I was to enter this the way I think it expects then I would end up with `ARCustomers("/:CustomerName/")` but unfortunately when I do that it gets translated in the curl like so `ARCustomers("/TEST/")'` (adding the unnecessary `/`s).

**How do I set a path variable without the forward slashes, is this not possible?**

Additionally in this example I'm using `"` around my path variable but I actually need it to be `'`, unfortunately that two is causing issues with forward slashes in my cURL

Comment: why you want to use path varaible and not normal variable ?

Comment: I don't want this stored (buried) as a environment or collection variable because the expectation here is that it would be changed regularly as we use this for troubleshooting and testing. Query variables come after the `?` so I was hoping to leverage the path variable

Comment: You can modify variable from pre-request as pm.variables.set("name",value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**if your url is like :**

```
https://my-domain.com/AR/ARCustomers("/:CustomerName/")
```

**Then in pre-request script use:**

```
path = pm.request.toJSON().url.variable.find((a)=>a.key==="CustomerName").value

console.log(pm.request.url.toString())
pm.request.url=pm.request.url.toString().replace(`/${path}/`,path)
console.log(pm.request.url.toString())
```

Postman properties are exposed through pm object and you can modify most properties except body from prerequest script.

**Here we are replacing /content/ with content**